# Turn OFF/ON condition related on variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have variable `,@UseClarifiedChangeType  INT = ISNULL(CAST([Config].[fn_Configuration_Get]('LCSP_ExecChanges_UseClarifiedChangeType') AS INT), 0)`

And in middle of sql I have condition `AND ISNULL(CHT.ClarifiedChangeType, ECH.ChangeType) IN ('Joining', 'Promotion', 'Internal Move')`

I need to use it only if `@UseClarifiedChangeType` is 1

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Negate the boolean

```
AND (
   @UseClarifiedChangeType != 1 
   OR ISNULL(CHT.ClarifiedChangeType, ECH.ChangeType) IN ('Joining', 'Promotion', 'Internal Move')
)
```

This test will pass if either

- @UseClarifiedChangeType is 1 and your `ISNULL(...)` part is true
- @UseClarifiedChangeType is something other than 1 (in which case the `IsNULL(...)` part is never run)

Comment: I need to run isnull only if useclarifiedchangetype is 1

Comment: @EugeneSukh ok I might have misunderstood - what do you want to run if useclarifiedchangetype is anything else other than 1?

Comment: I just don’t want to run nothing

Comment: Then this should do the trick @EugeneSukh

Comment: That's a double negative, @EugeneSukh . If you don't want to run nothing, you do want to run something.

Comment: @Larnu I think they meant "I don't not want to run nothing" - ;)